# Removing functions from Python Toolbox Template?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, arctoolbox, python-toolbox

I've been working on a new Python Toolbox, which is getting quite large, and am wondering what of the [template](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/creating-tools/a-template-for-python-toolboxes.htm) can be trimmed off when not used.

In the template there are functions like `isLicensed`, `updateParameters`, `updateMessages` etc., which most of the time I don't modify.  If I'm not modifying them from their original state (which is usually just a `return` or a `return True`, can they be safely removed?

I did a quick test where I just commented out these extra functions, and haven't seen any issues raised about them not being there, but haven't been able to find anything definitive about what needs to be there and what is optional.  Maybe they are required by ArcToolbox somehow.

The Python Toolbox template with unused functions commented out:

```
import arcpy
class Toolbox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the toolbox (the name of the toolbox is the name of the
        .pyt file)."""
        self.label = "Toolbox"
        self.alias = ""

        # List of tool classes associated with this toolbox
        self.tools = [Tool]

class Tool(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the tool (tool name is the name of the class)."""
        self.label = "Tool"
        self.description = ""
        self.canRunInBackground = False

    def getParameterInfo(self):
        """Define parameter definitions"""
        params = None
        return params

    # Commented out as not being used    
    #def isLicensed(self):
    #    """Set whether tool is licensed to execute."""
    #    return True

    # Commented out as not being used
    #def updateParameters(self, parameters):
    #    """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
    #    validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
    #    has been changed."""
    #    return

    # Commented out as not being used
    #def updateMessages(self, parameters):
    #    """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
    #    parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""
    #    return

    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        """The source code of the tool."""
        return
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is that ArcToolbox is a window within ArcMap, ArcCatalog and the 3D applications, after earlier being a separate application.  As such I think that it is quite independent of any Python Toolboxes (*.pyt), although both are parts of the same over-arching Geoprocessing Framework.

I think deleting those unused functions would be fine, when you do not need them, because the [Defining a tool in a Python toolbox](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/creating-tools/defining-a-tool-in-a-python-toolbox.htm) help says:

> Tools are added to a `.pyt` as classes. Each tool class should include
>   at a minimum an `__init__` and `execute` method. Optionally,
>   `getParameterInfo`, `isLicensed`, `updateParameters`, and `updateMessages`
>   methods can be used to add additional control to the behavior of the
>   tool.

However, if your main reason for removing functions is to stop *.pyt files being so big then there is also the option to remove code of other functions out into separate scripts from where you can call them as Python modules.  I am pretty sure that this is documented briefly somewhere else but [Extending geoprocessing through Python modules](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/python/extending-geoprocessing-through-python-modules.htm) may be worth being aware of, if you are not already.

Comment: I thought I had been through all the links under "Creating Tools in a Python Toolbox" but somehow missed the one page that gave the answer!

Comment: I may have used the wrong term with "ArcToolbox" and probably should have said "Geoprocessing Framework".  Was more wondering if each function was required by ArcGIS somehow.  But you've given the answer I needed.